AttributeError: 'numpy.int64'. Here is my object has no attribute 'loc'
I am trying to sum up the values of a column based on if condition from 2 columns but I am getting error AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' has no attribute 'loc'.
Here is my  object:
df3 = df3.loc[(df3['Feature Name'] == 'GI - MIPS PI - Filter Scorecard Data Panel - Measures(All) - PI_HIE_1: Support Electronic Referral Loops by Sending Health Information Measure Checkbox',) & (df3['Practice Management Software'] == 'Intergy'), 'Events'].sum()

I was expecting it to return values of sum of events column.

print df3 prior to running the above - likely at some point before you're replacing it with integer.

Sir, please show the result of str(df3) or df3.dtypes and df3.head(n=5).
